# Angular Directive $watch not responding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am trying to use d3 and angular together. I have set up the following d3 modules:

```
angular.module('DTBS.d3', [])
  .factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope',
    function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
      var d = $q.defer();
      function onScriptLoad() {
        // Load client in the browser
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.d3); });
      }
      // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
      // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
      // has been loaded
      var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
      scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      scriptTag.async = true;
      scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
      scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
      }
      scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

      var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      s.appendChild(scriptTag);

      return {
        d3: function() { return d.promise; }
      };
}]);

angular.module('DTBS.directives', [])
  .directive('d3Bars', ['d3Service', function (d3Service) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
          // d3 code goes here
          var svg = d3.select(element[0])
          .append("svg")
          .style('width', '100%');

          scope.render = function (data) {
            // remove all previous items before render
            svg.selectAll('*').remove();
            // If we don't pass any data, return out of the element
            if (!data) return;
            svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data).enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('height', 50)
            .attr('width', 50)
            .style('background-color', red)
          };

          // set up watch to see if button clicked; add rectangle with render func
          scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
            console.log("hey")
            return scope.render(newVals);
          }, true);
        });
      }};
  }]);
```

In the main part of my code I have a module called 'DTBS.test'. This module has a Table Controller that has a function called 'save'. I want my d3 directive to watch for this save function to be called, and when it is, the render function should be called to add a rectangle to the svg.

```
angular.module('DTBS.test', [])
.controller('TableController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var secondsToWaitBeforeSave = 3;
    $scope.table = {};
    //Table save function that clears form and pushes up to the parent
    $scope.save = function () {
      $scope.id++;
      $scope.table.id = $scope.id;
      $scope.table.attrs = [];
      $scope.addTable($scope.table);
      $scope.table = {};
    };

  }])
```

At the moment it is watching for changes to 'data' which doesn't exist - my question is what should it watch for and how to link the event in the test module's controller to the watch setup in the d3 module's directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an intermediate data service so that anything can manipulate the D3 data if so inclined.  That data service can broadcast events, that your directive can catch to rerender your data.

```
.service('d3Data', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var data = [];
  var emit = function(data) { $rootScope.$broadcast('d3:new-data', data); }
  var api = {
    get: function() {
      return data;
    },
    set: function(data) {
      data = data;
      emit(data);
      return data;
    },
    push: function(datum) {
      data.push(datum);
      emit(data);
      return data;
    }
  }

  return api;
}])
```

I've created a few little helper functions in case you need them.  Not a lot would change in your directive.  Just adding a way to catch the events instead of a `watch`.  You can put this below your `scope.render` function.

```
scope.$on('d3:new-data', function(e, data) {
   scope.render(data);
});
```

Next, you'll have that controller that wants to talk to the D3 chart.

```
.controller('TableController', ['$scope', 'd3Data', function ($scope, d3Data) {
  $scope.table = {};
  //Table save function that clears form and pushes up to the parent
  $scope.save = function(data) {
    data = angular.copy(data);
    d3Data.push(data);
  };
}])
```

The template will provide the `save` function the data through the ng-models.  Hypothetically, you'll have some inputs in your template with ng-models such as `table.width` and `table.height`, then for your submit button you can put `ng-click="save(table)"`.  Then we copy that data so it's no longer two-way bound to the form.  And push the data using our new d3Data service, which will broadcast a message, which the directive will catch and update the data.

I've created a simple Plunk to demonstrate this.  http://plnkr.co/edit/VMRNvZ?p=preview

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly! Cannot thank you enough, amazing with the working plunker too

Answer (score 0):

The one big issue that I am seeing is that `data` variable is only available within the `render` function. You are calling `$watch` outside `render` where `data` is `undefined`.

A simple solution would be as follows:

```
scope.data;
scope.render = function (data) {
     scope.data = data;
     // some code here
}

scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
}
```

Comment: I disagree with this.  It's better to have render as a pure function (as the original example shows).  The only thing needed to make their example work would be to add `scope.data = [ // data here ]` pretty much anywhere in the link function